# Is it possible to set FIRStorageUploadTask to only use a WiFi connection?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to set FIRStorageUploadTask to only use a WiFi connection?  I see no way to access the NSURLSession used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting in the Firebase Storage SDK to control what connection it uses. If you want to limit uploads to only happen over wifi, you should check the connection yourself and start/cancel the tasks when a relevant network switch over occurs.